# Обращение к свойству объекта a.field или a[field]

Tags: javascript

Ребят, не пойму в чем ошибка. Есть задача на всем известном сайте для изучения JS по организации сортировки объектов в массиве через замыкания. В общем не пойму, почему при обращении к свойству объекта через точку `return a.field > b.field ? 1 : -1;` сортировка работает не верно, а через скобки `return a[field] > b[field] ? 1 : -1;` верно, хотя название свойства в одно слово без пробелов.

```js
var users = [{
  name: "Вася",
  surname: 'Иванов',
  age: 20
}, {
  name: "Петя",
  surname: 'Чапаев',
  age: 25
}, {
  name: "Маша",
  surname: 'Медведева',
  age: 18
}];


function byField(field){
  return function (a, b){
      return a[field] > b[field] ? 1 : -1;
  }
}

users.sort(byField('name'));
users.forEach(function(user) {
  alert( user.name );
}); // Вася, Маша, Петя

users.sort(byField('age'));
users.forEach(function(user) {
  alert( user.name );
}); // Маша, Вася, Петя
```

Comment: где пример с демонстрацией проблемы то? у вас две сортировки по имени и по возрасту, судя по комментариям выводят правильно. проблема не понятна.

Comment: У меня пример работает корректно. Все верно) Суть вопроса в тексте над кодом: если поставить вместо квадратных скобок точку - сортировка работать будет не верно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как я вижу `field` это аргумент функции, он имеет некое значение.

Так вот, когда Вы пишете `a[field]` Вы обращаетесь к полю, которое называется так, какое значение находится в переменной `field` т.е. например к полю `"name"`, а когда пишете `a.field` Вы обращаетесь к полю под названием `"field"`

Comment: Сам всегда задавался эти вопрос, оказывается всё так элементарно ))

Comment: точно) понял не с первого раза, а ведь действительно все просто и логично. Спасибо!

Comment: @Кафка Тамура, если решение вас удовлетворило, нажмите на галочку

Comment: @ВладиславЖидко да да, уже сделал) Спасибо!